# Azure Search Lucene (full query type) single character

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Cognitive Search with QueryType = SearchQueryType.Full. It works fine but it doesn't search a word leas or equal 3 characters e.g. "the", "AC" etc.

I have some specific words which contain two characters.

Is it possible to somehow turn on search by all words even have less or equal to 3 characters?

Update: I believe it's not a problem with a searching but with highlighting results .

Answer (score 0):

Having QueryType = SearchQueryType.Full is not a problem.

1. If you are using standard.lucene by default stopwards list is empty.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers#predefined-analyzers-reference
2. If you are using English language analyzer all common filling words will not be indexed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-language-analyzers#english-analyzers
3. If you are searching for words for "starts with" you need to use wild card at the end of each word. Ex: the* for searching theatre